# Path error in python

Tags: python

I have written a script to rename a file

```
import os
path = "C:\\Users\\A\\Downloads\\Documents\\"
for x in os.listdir(path):
    if x.startswith('i'):
        os.rename(x,"Information brochure")
```

When the python file is in a different directory than the path I get a file not found error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\A\Desktop\script.py", line 5, in <module>
os.rename(x,"Information brochure")
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:'ib.pdf'-> 'Information brochure'
```

But if I copy the python file to the path location it works fine

```
import os
for x in os.listdir('.'):
    if x.startswith('i'):
        os.rename(x,"Information brochure")
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: os.chdir(path) worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `x` is currently only the filename relative to `path`. It's what `os.listdir(path)` outputs. As a result, you need to prepend `path` to `x` using `os.path.join(path,x)`.

```
import os
path = "C:\\Users\\A\\Downloads\\Documents\\" #os.path.join for cross-platform-ness
for x in os.listdir(path):
    if x.startswith('i'): # x, here is the filename. That's why it starts with i.
        os.rename(os.path.join(path,x),os.path.join(path,"Information brochure"))
```

Comment: I would suggest using `os.rename(os.path.join(path,x),os.path.join(path,"Information brochure"))`

Comment: Yes `os.rename(os.path.join(path,x),os.path.join(path,"Information brochure"))` worked.I dont know what `os.rename(os.path.join(path,x),"Information brochure")` did but it deleted the file from the directory

Comment: @honeysingh Since you didn't give it the absolute path, it probably just moved the file to the current directory.

Comment: @sihrc yes it moved the file to current directory

Answer (score 0):

The `x` variable has the name of the file but not the full path to the file. Use this:

`os.rename(path + "\\" + x, "Information brochure")`

Comment: Actually, now I see sihrc, answer is better as it is more portable.